# Problem with If/Then code with Google Sheet Script

Tags: if-statement, command

Someone please help.

I am trying to create a simple script which records button presses in order.

I have:

```
function P1Buzzer() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row = 6;
var col = 1;
var Name = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row = 192;
var col = 1;
var AnswerPosition = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue();

if (AnswerPosition = 1) {
sheet.getRange(199, 1).setValue(Name);
var AnswerPosition = AnswerPosition + 1
sheet.getRange(192, 1).setValue(AnswerPosition);
}

if (AnswerPosition = 2) {
sheet.getRange(200, 1).setValue(Name);
var AnswerPosition = AnswerPosition + 1
sheet.getRange(192, 1).setValue(AnswerPosition);
}

}
```

The problem I have is that when I run the script it does both the commands, ignoring the `if` command.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, you are setting the value to 1 by using `=` instead of `==`.  Second, if it was 1, you add one to it and then check to see if it is 2.  I'll bet it is!

```
if (AnswerPosition == 1) {
  sheet.getRange(199, 1).setValue(Name);
  var AnswerPosition = AnswerPosition + 1
  sheet.getRange(192, 1).setValue(AnswerPosition);
} else if  (AnswerPosition == 2) {
```

...

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your prompt reply.

Comment: Your welcome but please mark the question answered.